# Just confused about a convergence/divergence problem:$\int_{1}^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan x}{x^{3/2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I'm trying to show that the following integral

**$$\int_{1}^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan x}{x^{3/2}}dx$$**

is convergent.

I tried to use comparison test and used the fact that **$x < \pi/2$** .
Therefore **$ (2/\pi )^{3/2}\int_{1}^{\pi /2}\ \tan\ x \ dx$** is less than the above integral and it diverges.
Hence the integral in question should also diverge, but it actually converges. Why?

Now when same integral is there but this time $x$ has power $1$ instead of $3/2$, then the integral is divergent, which can be shown by the same comparison test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may observe that, as $x \to \dfrac{\pi}2^-$, by the Taylor series expansion, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sin x&=1-O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^2\right)\\
\cos x&=-\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^3\right)\\
\end{align}
$$ giving
$$
\tan x =-\frac1{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}+O\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)
$$ and

> $$
> \frac{\tan x}{x^{3/2}} =-\frac{2^{3/2}}{\pi^{3/2}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)}+O\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right), \quad x \to \dfrac{\pi}2^-,
> $$

then, by the **comparison test** for integrals, the initial integral is **divergent** as is $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\pi/2}\frac{2^{3/2}}{\pi^{3/2}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)}dx$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to understand your taylor series expansion.

Comment: can you please explain how you got tan x expression.

Comment: @Pranjal16 Sure. For any nice function, you have, as $x \to a$, $f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac12f''(a)(x-a)^2+O((x-a)^3)$. Apply it to $f(x)=\sin x$, $a=\pi/2$ and to $f(x)=\cos x$, $a=\pi/2$.  Then you find the two Taylor expansions.